# React Want to update field when click on image

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have login class in which I am rendering login inputs as loginElement.
I can retrieve username and password successfully but I am getting error with pinpad.

When user click on pinpad image then it has to pick `data-field-id` from image and need to insert in first input above pinpad image using comma separated value.
And in next input I want number of clicked images.

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import LoginElement from './LoginElement'

class CurrentLogin extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
    }

    render() {
        
       {this.props.credentials.map(credentialElement => <LoginElement 
                            data={credentialElement} 
                            key={credentialElement.fieldID} 
                            inputValue={this.state.userInputValues[credentialElement.fieldID]}
                            onChange={this.onInputFieldChange(credentialElement.fieldID)}                                
                        />)}
        }
    }
```

**LoginElement.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
const LoginElement= (props) => {

    const [setImageIds] = useState('');

    switch (props.data.type.toLowerCase()) {
        case "text":
            return <div className="form-group">
                <label style={{display: "block"}}>{props.data.name}</label>
                {props.data.description &&
                    <span>{parse(props.data.description)}</span>
                }
                <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={props.onChange} />
            </div>

        case "password":
            return <div className="form-group">
                <label>{props.data.name}</label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control" onChange={props.onChange} />
            </div>

        case "pinpad":

            const onPinPadClick = key => event => {
                
            }

            let pinPadImages = props.data.pinpads;

            return <div className="form-group">
                <label style={{display: "block"}}>{props.data.name}</label>
                    <input type="hidden" className="form-control" />
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e) => setImageIds(e.target.value)}/>
                <div className="pin-pad-container">
                {Object.keys(pinPadImages).map(index => (
                    <img
                        src={pinPadImages[index].src}
                        alt=""
                        width={pinPadImages[index].width}
                        height={pinPadImages[index].height}
                        data-field-id={index}
                        data-field-type={pinPadImages[index].type}
                        className="pinpad"
                        onClick={onPinPadClick(index)}
                    />
                ))}
                </div>
            </div>



        default:
            return null
    }
}

export default LoginElement
```

I tried different methods but getting function not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with this line

```
const [setImageIds] = useState('');
```

The useState hook returns an array of two values: a state and a callback function to set some value to the state. If you want to get the callback function, you have to get the second value of the useState's returned array

```
const [imageIds, setImageIds] = useState('');
```